Etymology of Behemoth
In Job 40:15, there is a creature referred to as "behemot" (בהמות). One interpretation suggests it is the plural form of the word "behemah" (בהמה), meaning "beast". Since it is a single animal, the plural form should convey its greatness, not multitude

"Whoever kills an animal (behemah) shall make it good, animal for animal" (Leviticus 24:18)


"But now ask the beasts (behemot), and they will teach you; And the birds of the air, and they will tell you" (Job 12:7)

Another interpretation suggests that it originates from the Egyptian word "pꜣ jḥ mw," which means hippopotamus. This word later evolved into "behemot" in Hebrew. But it is still interesting for me, why would it take the plural form instead of singular. Did they think that "behemot" somehow sounds closer to "pꜣ jḥ mw" than "behemah"?

Is this a statement or a question?

Do you really mean hippocampus, as in a region of the brain, or a hippopotamus?

Yeah, I meant hippopotamus
